# Unable to Extend Ubuntu Partition Size

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to increase the size of my Ubuntu partition.

My partitions, overall, are sort of a mess. I don't know what the System Reserved /sda1 partition is, but I figure that's something to do with Windows 7 and haven't touched it. Anywho, I'm trying to merge the unallocated space with the /dev/sda6 partition, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it using GParted.

Do I have to use the LiveCD for that? 
And if so, do I use the Ubuntu liveCD or some other disk? I'll attach a window-screengrab from GParted running in Ubuntu.

Screengrab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhtR1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alter a mounted partition. Obviously your `/dev/sda6` partition is mounted (since it contains root, `/`) since you're running Ubuntu with it. Also, the little key icon/symbol indicates that it is locked (a.k.a in use).

So yes you'll need to boot into a `LiveCD` or `LiveUSB` in order to do this.